# For using an inverter, what determines the power usage?

Tags: voltage, power, batteries, inverter

Say I have a 12V battery hooked up to an inverter (assume no inefficiency). I guessed that if a 1A, 120V draw was placed on it, because 120W was pulled from the inverter, it would pull 120W, and therefore 12V/10A from the 12V battery. Is this assumption flawed?

Comment: Yes, because your 100% efficiency assumption is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is true, power is conserved if you have a 'magical' inverter that converts energy at 100% efficiency.

For a real world inverter however, you need an efficency rating, usually 80-95% but could be lower. For a real world inverter the power out can only be lower than the power in, and if your doing any kind of sizing its better to estimate the efficiency with a lower number.

$$ P_{in}*Efficency = P_{out} $$